# mysql join query help

Tags: mysql, join

I am using mysql db.
I have 2 tables.
I'm building a user suggestion list which selects user list from 2 tables.
First `table (users)` have the user information.
Second `table (followers)` contains follow list.
I need to select suggestions

My query is like

```
SELECT a.*, b.userid, b.friendid, a.userid 
FROM users a,followers b 
WHERE a.userid != '$uid' 
AND (b.friendid != a.userid AND b.userid != '$uid')
```

But this query returns all the data including already followed users also.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never query .* it is bad style.

Answer (score 0):

You're not joining the two tables, so you're going to get everything that isn't excluded by the WHERE clause.

Your question is a bit unclear, but I suspect you're looking for:

```
SELECT a.*, b.userid, b.friendid, a.userid 
FROM users a,followers b 
WHERE a.userid != '$uid' 
AND b.userid = a.userid
AND b.friendid != a.userid
```

Comment: I am trying to get unique suggestions from tables which is not already followed. But i am getting duplicates from the both 2 queries

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from users 
 where userid != '$uid' and 
 userid not in (select friendid from followers where userid='$uid')
```

Comment: Try that on a table with any sizeable number of rows. Call me when it finishes ;) When you use `IN` like that you create a linear search for each row in the main query.

Comment: @brian : on mysql 5.1 its fixed.

Comment: @Raj please accept this as answer with the tick on the left of the question.